# Xcode: Is there a keyboard shortcut which makes the editor have focus?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In xcode, after flicking to any of the navigators, say the Project Navigator (⌘ 1), I'd like to flick back to the editor.

Is there a keyboard shortcut which makes the editor have focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.